# Cannot allocate memory for a 2 dimentional array of pointers c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array of pointers to a object of type Piece. The problem is when i try assign a pointer to a piece to the array i get a segmentation fault. I realized I needed to initialize to array to sometime before I can start allocating but I can't get it right.

Here is the header file of Map which contains a 2-d array of pointers.

```
#ifndef MAP_H
 #define MAP_H

 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstring>
 #include "Player.h"
 #include "Sprite.h"
 #include "Piece.h"
 #include "Messages.h"
 #include "PieceType.h" 

using namespace std;

class Map
{
    private:

        Piece*** pieces;
        int startingX;
        int startingY;
        int width;
        int height;
        string mapName;

    public:

        Map(string);
        ~Map();

        void printMap() const;
        Piece* pieceType(char);
        void setSprite(Piece*);
        void firstMove();
        void resetMap(string);

        bool moveUp(int, int);
        bool moveDown(int, int);
        bool moveLeft(int, int);
        bool moveRight(int, int);

        int getHeight();
        int getWidth();


};

#endif
```

The array I'm talking about is pieces.

I try to allocate this in the constructor of Map.

```
Map::Map(string name)
{
  ifstream map;
  string line;
  string dimention;
  mapName = name;

  map.open(name.c_str());

  if (map.good())
  {
    getline (map, line);

    int i = 0;

    while(line[i] != 'X')
    {
      dimention[i] = line[i];
      i++;
    }

    stringstream convert(dimention);

    convert >> width;

    int temp = i;
    dimention = "";
    i = 1;

    while(line[(i + temp)] != '\0')
    {
      dimention[i] = line[(i + temp)];
      i++;
    }

    stringstream convertTwo(dimention);

    convertTwo >> height;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
       if (!(map.eof()))
       { 
     getline (map, line);
       }
       else
       {
     cout << "Error with file" << endl;
     break;
       }

       for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {
     pieces[i][j] = pieceType(line[j]); //This is where I'm getting the segmentation fault

     cout << "assigned" << endl;

     if ((pieces[i][j])->getType() == WAYPOINT)
     {

       if (pieces[i][j]->getWaypointType() == 0)
       {
         startingX = j;
         startingY = i;
       }
     }

     else
     {       
     (pieces[i][j])->setXCordinate(j);
     (pieces[i][j])->setYCordinate(i);
     }

       }
     }
  }
}
```

Where name is a string that holds the name of the file that has the information for loading a particular map.

Also the function pieceType is as follows:

```
Piece* Map::pieceType(char type)
{
  Piece* temp;

  if (type == '.')
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (type == 'S')
  {
    temp = new Waypoint(0);
    return temp;
  }
  if (type == 'E')
  {
    temp = new Waypoint(1);
    return temp;
  }
}
```

Waypoint is a derived class of Piece.

Comment: I assume the size of the array is unknown at compile time? Is there any limit to the array size?

Comment: you are de-refencing 'pieces' before you allocate it, even if it is pointers you need allocate the pointers. better yet, use std:vector instead to keep track of what and when to delete your pointers e.g. `vector<vector<Piece*>> pieces;`

Comment: `pieces[i][j] = pieceType(line[j]);` this is not allocation of memory, this is assignment of value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed that you have to initialize that array. Like this:

```
pieces=new Piece**[height];
for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
     pieces[i]=new Piece*[width];
}
```

Write that just after you get `width` and `height`, and before you start using `pieces`.
But something you should know: for each `new`, there should be a corresponding `delete`, or else that memory will never be freed, and you will get a memory leak. To free that memory, add this in your destructor:

```
for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        delete pieces[i][j];
    }
    delete[] pieces[i];
}
delete[] pieces;
```

This assumes that every `pieces[i][j]` contains either an object allocated with `new` or NULL, and it works with both. Looking at your code, that seems to be your case. However, it would not work if one of them is not assigned (not your case).

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<std::vector<Pieces>>`instead of (trying to, because it does not work) reinventing the wheel. Its safe, easy, and avoids getting manual-memory-management headaches.